# Singularitygs Grid overlay Not Showing

Tags: sass, singularitygs

Singularitygs Grid overlay Not Showing
This is driving me up the wall, i've finally got singularity working but can't seam to show the grid - if someone could help that would be great.

Not bothered about the fancy toggle solution just want to see the grid-overlay desperately!

My HTML

```
<body data-development-grid="show">
```

My SASS

```
@import "singularitygs"
// Singularity 1.2 Syntax
@include add-grid(12)
@include add-gutter(1/3)

.container
 @include background-grid
 max-width: 940px
 margin: 0 auto
 min-height: 100%

.one
 background-color: black
 width: 100px
 height: 100px
 top: 2px
 left: 5px
```

If it helps i'm using codekit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Indeed that doesn't work for some reason: http://sassmeister.com/gist/320bc862a801eed8e462 . I tried reproducing that in a Compass project, the result is the same and Singularity won't spit out any warnings.

Comment: got it working now :) added @include sgs-change ('debug', true)

Comment: Ah! I'm still on Singularity 1.1, so i wasn't aware of that. Consider completing your question with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working. The solution is to apply `sgs-change ('debug', true)`.

Here's my Sass code if anyone needs it:

```
@import "breakpoint"
@import "singularitygs"


//////////////////////
// Set up the grid  //
//////////////////////

+add-grid(12)
+add-gutter(1/3)
+add-gutter-style('split')
+sgs-change ('debug', true)

body
 @include background-grid
```

Demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/fa0ac03b02e604f6bdf6

Comment: Wow, awesome! A valuable contribution, taking into consideration that the `debug` option is never mentioned in Singularity wiki. Where did you find it? PS I've edited your answer a bit: mentioned which directive is the solution, removed "asymmetric" as the example is symmetric, used shorthand Sass syntax, added a Sassmeister demo.

Comment: I've filed an issue to Singularity tracker: https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/issues/190